# htmlコードをrailsでリファクタリングしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#" role="button">
   <%= fa_icon 'twitter' %>
   Twitterで登録/ログイン</a>
</li>
```

上のhtml文を下記のようにrailsでリファクタリングしようとしたが、同じように表示されないので正しいコードがわかる人がいましたらお力貸してください。

```
<li class="nav-item">
 　<%= link_to root_path do %>
   　<%= fa_icon 'twitter', class: 'nav_link', role: "button" %>
  　 Twitterで登録/ログイン
   <% end %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a`要素に指定されていた属性が`link_to`ではなく`fa_icon`に移っているのがおかしいです。

それ以前に、このコードはlink_toを使って書き換える意味がありません。